# Delete Album from table by url - django

Tags: python, django

I added to the list of my albums - a press button that delete the currnt object mention by "pk"\"id".
I show you the code:

```
{% for album in albums %}
    <a href="{%  url 'index'  %}{{ album.id }}">{{ album.name }}</a>

    <form action="{{ album.pk }}" method="post">
{% csrf_token %}
    <button type="submit">push</button>

    </form>
    <br />
{% endfor %}
```

and url.py:

```
 url(r'(?P<pk>[0-9])', views.delete.as_view()),
```

and, the Delete view:

```
class delete(DeleteView):
    model = Album
    success_url = reverse_lazy('index')
```

when i press the button, its really delete what i need from the table.
But i tried to send the id by artificial - just wrote it myself in the url line, and the same action didnt do the same behavior. it sent me to an error page.

why those are two differents behaviors in two same actions?

Comment: When you tried to specify the ID manually on the url, did that ID exist?  Or had it already been deleted (or never existed)?

Comment: Does DeleteView require that the request method be POST?

Comment: May be its why it doesnt happend at the second time... so i can i check i the self object is post..? and if its not a post, so what happend exactly when i type the url by myself?(and yes, the id is exist.)

Comment: If you type a URL directly into the browser, the request type is GET.

Comment: Yes.. i know it. but how can i check it with the code? (for a situation that a user enter a url by himself)